# Are there any articles (or otherwise) that discuss the idea that the set-theoretic universe should be as "free" as possible?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, axioms, foundations

> **Question.** Are there any articles (or otherwise) that discuss (and perhaps attempt to formalize) the idea that the set-theoretic universe should be as "free" as possible?

*Discussion.* Philosophically speaking, a structure is *free* iff it has

1. no inaccessible elements (hence very few substructures), and
2. no unnecessary identifications (hence very many quotients.)

Now suppose we take the viewpoint that the set-theoretic universe should be as "free" as possible. Then condition (1) suggests a variety of axioms, all of which are somehow kind of  "limiting":

- "no inaccessible elements" suggests that "no inaccessible cardinals" is a reasonable axiom.
- "very few substructures" suggests that $V=L$ is a reasonable axiom (since if I recall correctly, $V=L$ is somehow equivalent to saying that the universe has no proper inner models.)

The problem is that if $V=L$ holds, then so too does GCH, and my gut feeling is that GCH implies that "the universe is chock-full of unnecessary identifications, and has very few quotients." So this kind of violates condition (2).

In conclusion, it seems that its very hard to get this "maximize freeness" idea off the ground. I'd like to know if anyone has had any more luck than me with the problem, hence the question.

Comment: Most papers are trying to convince the reader to believe large cardinal axioms are reasonable. Not to argue against them. Moreover, to argue about "unnecessary identifications" you actually argue against the axiom of choice in a very severe way, rather than against $\sf GCH$. It seems to me that you'd be very happy in Gitik's model where every ordinal has a countable cofinality.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes and no. The consequences of "maximize freeness" are very hard to understand, since it both suggests $V=L$, also $\neg AC$ as well as $\neg GCH$. Until we can sort this out, its not at all clear "maximize freeness" argues for or against. Ideally, a good article would define terms like "quotient of $M$" where $M$ is a model of ZFC, and use this to motivate axioms inside a more rigorous framework, rather than the kind of ad hoc analysis in my question, that leads so uncomfortably to the axiom schema $V=L+\neg\mathrm{AC}$.

Comment: Hooray!!!  We just argued for large cardinals!